# React useContext cannot make simple counter work

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to make a simple example illustrating how useContext work.
I have started with this sandbox code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-usecontext-lama-1v7wd

The issue is that the component `Counter` does not update and rerender when I click the button.

My index

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { MyContextProvider, MyContext } from './Context'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

const MyCounter = () => {
    const context = useContext(MyContext)
    const { counter } = context
    const { setCounter } = context

    return (
        <div>
            Valeur du compteur : {counter}
            <br />
            <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter - 1)} type="button">
                -1
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)} type="button">
                +1
            </button>
            <br />
            <button onClick={() => setCounter(0)} type="button">
                RàZ
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
render(
    <MyContextProvider>
        <MyCounter />
    </MyContextProvider>,
    rootElement
)
```

My context:

```
type MyContextProps = {
    counter: number
    setCounter: Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>
}

const MyContext = createContext({} as MyContextProps)

const MyContextProvider: React.FunctionComponent = (props) => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState<number>(0)

    return (
        <MyContext.Provider
            value={{
                counter: 0,
                setCounter: setCounter,
            }}
        >
            {props.children}
        </MyContext.Provider>
    )
}

export { MyContext, MyContextProvider }
```

It's got to be something elementary, but I just can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a small error.

in your context, you have set your counter to be always zero. Change this to be `counter` state and your problem should be resolved.

```
const MyContextProvider: React.FunctionComponent = (props) => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState<number>(0)

    return (
        <MyContext.Provider
            value={{
                counter: counter, //<-- HERE. 
                setCounter: setCounter,
            }}
        >
            {props.children}
        </MyContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

As a suggestion, consider using function to get the latest state of your value when setting the next value using the `setCounter` function, if the next value is dependent on the previous value.

The mutation function from `useState` can also accept a callback function, which provides the latest current state and should return the next state value based on the previous value. This is especially helpful if setting state is in an async operation preventing stale closures.

(prevValue) => nextValue

```
 <button onClick={() => setCounter(prevValue => prevValue - 1)} type="button">
```

and

```
  <button onClick={() => setCounter(prevValue => prevValue + 1)} type="button">
```